# A method adding an event calling an other method

Tags: javascript, events, methods, this

I need to create an object that have at least two methods. The first method creates an event that bind a button to the second method of the object.

But, I have a problem at the creation of the event. The `this` keeps being attached to the button and not the instance of the object.

I tried `bind()` but if it is the solution I didn't find the good way to use it.

Is it even possible to do that? And, if yes, how can it be done?

```js
function obj()
{
  this.attribute = 42;
  this.eventer();
}

obj.prototype.eventer = function()
{
  $("#but").on("click",this.print);
}

obj.prototype.print = function()
{
  $("#print").html(this.attribute);
}

var test = new obj();
```

```html
<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script> 
<button id="but">Click me !</button>
<div id="print"></div>
```

Comment: How did you try to use `bind`? Please show us your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the javascript reference manual for [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Simply use `this.print.bind(this)`, when passing the handler to the click event.

```js
function obj()
{
  this.attribute = 42;
  this.eventer();
}

obj.prototype.eventer = function()
{
  $("#but").on("click",this.print.bind(this));
}

obj.prototype.print = function()
{
  $("#print").html(this.attribute);
}

var test = new obj();
```

```html
<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script> 
<button id="but">Click me !</button>
<div id="print"></div>
```